# How can I use exec in PHP with Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, exec

I do not think I want to use `exec` or `shell_exec` but I need to run command in Linux from PHP script. I use Symfony framework in the project.

I must get listing of directories using `ls -la`.

Comment: There's quite a few functions in PHP that you can use. opendir(), readdir().

Answer (score 4):

Symfony has a Process component to handle native system calls.

See: https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/process.html

An example from the docs:

```
use Symfony\Component\Process\Process;
use Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\ProcessFailedException;

$process = new Process('ls -la');
$process->run();

// executes after the command finishes
if (!$process->isSuccessful()) {
    throw new ProcessFailedException($process);
}

echo $process->getOutput();
```

Answer (score 3):

Symfony has a [Filesystem Component](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/filesystem.html) for work with files and directories. However, it does not have the ability to list files in a directory. The [scandir](http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php) function built into PHP can do that for you. This would be better than issuing direct commands to the OS.

Answer (score 0):

Use fromShellCommandline to use direct shell command:

```
use Symfony\Component\Process\Process;
use Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\ProcessFailedException;

Process::fromShellCommandline('ls -la');
$process->run();

// executes after the command finishes
if (!$process->isSuccessful()) {
    throw new ProcessFailedException($process);
}

echo $process->getOutput();
```